# how to insert a marker to point out to specific location in Google maps?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

```
<head>

    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script>
        function initialize() {
            var mapProp = {
                center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
                zoom:5,
                mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
</head>

<body>  

    <div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>

</body>
```

I am using the above code to insert Google maps in my website. It is showing the place but I want to insert a pointer or marker to be there in a specific address. Can I get some help in regarding how to insert it?

Comment: What is the address or the coordinates at which you want to place the marker?  If it is by "address" you will need to use the [geocoder]((https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) to determine the coordinates for the marker.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `google.maps.Marker` constructor with a lat/long, map and title.

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Hello World!'
  });
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers